# Is there another way to extract data dump from Planet.osm?

Tags: xml, extract, openstreetmap

I need a data dump from planet.osm fiel for the NCR region in the Philippines. I'll be using it for an OpenStreetMap project. Is there a way that I can extract a small part of the planet.osm without downloading the whole file? I mean, the planet.osm file is 11GB in size, and I'll be only needing a fraction of it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a really small area you need to cover, you can directly get the raw OpenStreetMap XML data of that area by opening http://www.openstreetmap.org/ in your browser, zooming to the desired area, clicking the *Export* tab on the top and then selecting *OpenStreetMap XML data* as the output format.

Another option is to just download a ready-made extract of `planet.osm` that contains the Philippines. For a list of download sites that offer *Planet.osm* extracts see [the OpenStreetMap wiki on *Planet.osm*](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Extracts) – Geofabrik for instance [offers an extract of the Philippines](http://download.geofabrik.de/osm/asia/).

Comment: You're my savior! I'm looking for this for weeks! How can I repay you? LOL... Seriously, this is really what I need. Thanks a lot! :D